# Find integral using the divergence theorem

Tags: calculus

$F=[x^2,y^2,z^2]$ , $S$ is the surface of a cone $x^2 +y^2 \leq z^2$ and $0 \leq z\leq h$

here is what I got so far

$$\operatorname{div} F= 2x +2y +2z$$

I tried to use the polar coordinate so I let

$$x= r\cos(\theta)$$

$$y= r\sin(\theta)$$

so $z \geq r$ and

$$\operatorname{div} F= 2r\cos(\theta) +2r\sin(\theta) +2z\text{ with }\leq r\leq z\text{ and }0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$$

$$\int_0^h\int_0^z\int_0^{2\pi}2r\cos(\theta) +2r\sin(\theta) +2z \, d\theta \, dr \, dz$$

I tried to calculate this integral and got $4h^3 \frac{\pi}{3}$ and the book said it should be $h^4 \frac {\pi}{2}$ so clearly I must have been mess up somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed in going in polar coordinates. Indeed, 
$$
\int\int\int f(x, y, z)dx dy dz = \int\int\int f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z) \color{red}{\underline{r}}d\theta dr dz
$$
and not
$$
\int\int\int f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z) d\theta dr dz
$$
because you have to keep up three dimensions, $dxdydz$ is a volume (three length that you multiply), but $d\theta drdz$ is just two lengths multiplied with $d\theta$ which has no dimension. Instead, $rd\theta dr dz$ is a volume. That's how you can replace $dxdydz$ by $rd\theta dr dz$.

Adding this $r$ in the integral you find $h^4 \frac\pi2$

Comment: +1 this is fine even though for the explanation of why you need to add $r$ I would insert a link to the general case, with the determinant of the jacobian matrix